# Accordion with Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-accordion

I am trying to make accordion with `Bootstrap Collapse`. I have this `HTML`:

```
<ul id="ul">
    <li>
        <div class="first">
             <button>
                 <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
             </button>
             <a href="#">Name</a>
         </div>
        <ul class="collapse">
            <li>
                <a href="#">item 1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">item 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When I click on `#ul > li`, it must show `ul.collapse`.

I am using this `JS`:

```
$('#ul > li').on('click', function (e) {
    $('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
    $(this).find('.collapse').collapse();
});
```

, but it works only first 2 clicks for open and close and after that, it doesn't work. I need to do this with `JS`.

Comment: You don't seem to be using [Bootstrap's collapse api](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse).

Comment: Also, you have a syntax error in your list: `<ul id=-ul">`

Comment: You are not using the collapse API. That being the case - if you don't care if it uses the BS API, then you can use this simple accordion I recently built.
https://jsfiddle.net/gemlarin/5y3x672h/

Answer (score 1):

Try that

```
 $('#ul > li').on('click', function (e) {
  if($('.collapse').hasClass('in')) {
    $('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
  } else {
      $(this).find('.collapse').collapse('show');
  }
});
```

it can be written in better form but that will fix your issue.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: You can use `slideToggle()` from jQuery.

```js
$('#ul > li').on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).find('.collapse').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.collapse {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ul">
  <li>
    <div class="first">
      <button>
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
      <a href="#">Ресторант Топ Мания</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="collapse">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Обедно меню</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Вечерно меню</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Option 2: use `collapse('hide')` and `collapse('show');`

```js
$('#ul > li').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.collapse.in').collapse('hide');
  $(this).find('.collapse').collapse('show');
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<ul id="ul">
  <li>
    <div class="first">
      <button>
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
      <a href="#">Ресторант Топ Мания</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="collapse">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Обедно меню</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Вечерно меню</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```